# Expand $\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2}$ in a Laurent Series in the neighborhood of $z=i$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

**Question:** Expand $\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2}$ in a Laurent Series in the neighborhood of $z=i$.

**My Thoughts**: Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2}=\frac{1}{(z+i)^2(z-i)^2}$.  Since we want to find the Laurent series in a neighborhood of $z=i$, then let $w=z-i$.  Thus, $f(w)=\frac{1}{w^2(w+2i)^2}$.  Now I am just a bit stuck.  I suppose we are really just playing with the definition of Laurent series of $$
  f(z) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n & \text{if $|z|<1$} \\
                                   -\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{z^n} & \text{if $|z|>1$} 
   & 
  \end{cases}
.
$$
and I will just want to write $\frac{1}{w^2}$ and $\frac{1}{(w+2i)^2}$ in the above form, which would inevitably make the "bound" conditions on $z$ be $i$, thus getting us in a neighborhood of $z=i$, then replace $w$ with $z-1$ in the end.   Or, maybe I could do partial fraction decomposition and go about it in the same way after I do that... or, maybe there is something I am not seeing here.  Something just "feels off".  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: leave $\frac{1}{w^2}$ alone and generate the Taylor series for $\frac{1}{(w+2i)^2}$

so your Laurent series will have a second order pole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us start with $\frac1{z+i}$. We have, if $|z-i|<2$,\begin{align}\frac1{z+i}&=\frac1{2i+z-i}\\&=\frac1{2i}\times\frac1{1+\frac{z-i}{2i}}\\&=\frac1{2i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(z-i)^i}{(2i)^n}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(z-i)^n}{(2i)^{n+1}}.\end{align}Therefore\begin{align}\frac1{(z+i)^2}&=-\left(\frac1{z+i}\right)'\\&=-\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(z-i)^n}{(2i)^{n+1}}\right)'\\&=-\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(z-i)^n}{(2i)^{n+1}}\right)'\\&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac n{(2i)^{n+1}}(z-i)^{n-1}\\&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n+1}{(2i)^{n+2}}(z-i)^n.\end{align}So\begin{align}\frac1{(z^2+1)^2}&=\frac1{(z-i)^2}\times\frac1{(z+i)^2}\\&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n+1}{(2i)^{n+2}}(z-i)^{n-2}\\&=-\sum_{n=-2}^\infty\frac{n+3}{(2i)^{n+4}}(z-i)^n.\end{align}

Comment: Why  $-\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z-i)^n}{(2i)^{n+1}} \right)' = -\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(z-i)^n}{(2i)^{n+1}} \right)'$ ? For $n = 0$ we get $\frac{1}{2i}$.

Comment: Indeed. And if you differentiate $\frac1{2i}$, then you get $0$, right?!

Comment: Oh, right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(w)=\frac{1}{w^2(w+2i)^2}=\frac{1}{w^2}\frac{1}{(w+2i)^2}$$ Using the binomial theorem
$$\frac{1}{(w+2i)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty-i^n \frac{ (n+1)}{2^{n+2} }w^n$$
$$f(w)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty-i^n \frac{ (n+1)}{2^{n+2} }w^{n-2}$$